# Running EMMA with JMockit and JUnit in Maven

Tags: maven-2, junit4, jmockit

I have a problem when running EMMA code coverage tool with JMockit + JUnit in maven.

I have a project and I am using JMockit as a mocking framework in it.

Once I run **mvn test** it is running successfully without any problem. That’s means JMockit is initializing with JUnit in a proper way.

Following is the way how I define my dependency for JMockit and JUnit within my POM (in the exact order).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.11</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

But When I check the project for code coverage with EMMA, it says

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit wasn't properly initialized; check that jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath (if using JUnit; if not, check the documentation)
```

but I think I have configured EMMA plugin correctly and it is given below,

```
<build>
<defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
<plugins>

<!—Some other plugins here -->

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <check>
                <classRate>100</classRate>
                <methodRate>100</methodRate>
                <blockRate>70</blockRate>
                <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
            </check>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Can anyone catch what is wrong there ?

Comment: What happens if you move JMockit down into test scope as well..

Comment: try running mvn -X. It might be extremely verbose, but you can see the entire classpath whenever a plugin goal is executed. That should give you a better indication of the load order.. Not sure why emma is so picky.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figured out what went wrong there. It seems that we need to specifically say JUnit to use JMockit when work with EMMA.

We can do it by using maven-surefire-plugin.

We need to add following configuration to the POM.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>
    <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/com/googlecode/jmockit/jmockit/1.7/jmockit-1.7.jar</argLine>
    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note: Make sure to change the location of JMockit Jar in above configuration.

Further, we do not need to have dependencies within EMMA plugin configuration. Just having them in a dependencies section in POM (in exact order) will be enough.

References:
[JMockit - initialization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905735/jmockit-initialization-problem)