# JMockIt fails with AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jmockit

I am developing a plugin for Eclipse Kepler. Adding @RunWith(JMockit.class) to my test class causes the following error:

```
    JMockit: Reinitializing under custom class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@b7ccec1[com.mypackage.myclass:2.3.9.201508161221(id=1)]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:407)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:170)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:242)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:236)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.applyClassModifications(MockClassSetup.java:134)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.redefineMethodsInClassHierarchy(MockClassSetup.java:91)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.redefineMethods(MockClassSetup.java:76)
        at mockit.MockUp.redefineMethods(MockUp.java:240)
        at mockit.MockUp.redefineClassOrImplementInterface(MockUp.java:222)
        at mockit.MockUp.<init>(MockUp.java:131)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.RunNotifierDecorator.<init>(RunNotifierDecorator.java:21)
        at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.loadInternalStartupMocksForJUnitIntegration(JMockitInitialization.java:42)
        at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.initialize(JMockitInitialization.java:27)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.applyStartupMocks(Startup.java:72)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.reapplyStartupMocks(Startup.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:94)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:159)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.reinitializeJMockitUnderCustomClassLoader(Startup.java:118)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.agentmain(Startup.java:101)
        ... 6 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.AbstractUITestApplication$1.run(AbstractUITestApplication.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.UITestApplication.runApplication(UITestApplication.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.AbstractUITestApplication.run(AbstractUITestApplication.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.UITestApplication.start(UITestApplication.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
        ... 39 more
```

Am I doing something wrong or it is a JMockIt bug? I am using version JMockIt  1.18, JUnit 4.12

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905735/jmockit-initialization-problem

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that `@RunWith(JMockit.class)` should have taken care of this problem.

In any case, from JMockit tutorial [here](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests), there are some notes that you should check, in case these resolve your issue. In particular, these two seem to be most relevant:

> - (Note for Eclipse users: when specifying the order of jars in the >classpath, make sure to use the "Order and Export" tab of the "Java Build >Path" window. Also, make sure the Eclipse project uses the JRE from a JDK >installation instead of a "plain" JRE, since the latter lacks the >"attach" native library.)
> - In other situations (like running on JDK implementations other than >the Oracle JDKs), you may need to pass "-javaagent:path>/jmockit.jar" as a JVM initialization parameter. This can be done in >the "Run/Debug Configuration" for both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA, or with >build tools such as Ant and Maven.

Comment: I am using the Oracle JDK, so it should not be the issue.

Comment: Have you checked the first point, i.e. specify jmockit before junit in the order and export tab?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is also needed only if you don't use the @RunWith(MockitoJUnit44Runner.class) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in Package Explorer

> click Properties.
>   go to Java Build Path.
>   Libraries tab.
>   click on 'Add Library' button select JUnit click Next. 
>   You should be able to handle it from there.

After that if you use coverage as : you will be able to see the coverage.

Answer (score 0):

pass the following paramter through the VM args.

```
-javaagent:<path>/jmockit.jar
```