# Spring Boot not finding JMockit.class

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, jmockit

**Context**

i'm trying to use jmockit with Spring boot

I'm using examples such as this:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-vs-easymock-vs-jmockito

I have set up the agent in my IDE jvm args:

```
-ea -javaagent:/path/to/lib_jmockit/jmockit-1.46.jar
```

However the IDE cannot find the JMockit.class. Nor can gradle. Help text shows: "Cannot resolve symbol JMockit"

[image: Intellij Cannot find JMockit.class]

Some points:

- Neither gradle nor intellij can find JMockit.class
- I've checked the Jmockit jar files. No JMockit.class

**Question**

- What class to  use instead of JMockit.class?
- can you point me to docs on how the various 'Runner' implementations work in testing? I'm new tot his and don't understand how runner "SpringJunit4ClassRunner" works differently from runner "JMockit.class" and what exactly a "Runner" implemenation does/doesn't do.

## Update

I ditched JMockit for Mockito. *"It just worked."*

Opinionated spring boot won over opinionated tech lead.

Comment: Stupid question. Why do you want to use another mocking framework. Spring Boot uses Mockito:

Comment: Tech lead wants likes Jmockit. I'm trying to 'give it a go.' In theory it should work.

Comment: Either you don't have JMockit in your project's test compile classpath, or you have a newer version where the `JMockit` class no longer exists. Check the documentation.

Comment: Tell your tech lead that Spring Boot is an opinionated framework and to get the most out of it you should use it as it is intended. This will also make update to future versions much easier.

Comment: This should probably help you out if you're still struggling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906690/3175251

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to get rid of "@RunWith(JMockit.class)" on your test.

A few versions of JMockit ago, the API allowed you EITHER use the javaagent, or to annotate tests with @RunWith.  A couple versions back, the API was changed to require javaagent, and the @RunWith was made obsolete.  I believe specifying it now breaks the test.